# How to Pass parameters to context.xml file in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin, and it has an extension as:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="contexts.xml"
            plugin="my.plugin.id">
      </contexts>
   </extension>
```

contexts.xml has:

```
<contexts>
   <context id="test_context" title="About Contexts">
      <description>This is written by me.</description>
      <topic href="http://www.google.com" label="Search about me" />
   </context>
</contexts>
```

and i am using it as:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "my.plugin.id.test_context");
```

Everything works fine, **but now i want to pass a parameter to contexts.xml**, so that based on that i can change the href.
For example now it is www.google.com , by passing parameters I want to change it to www.yahoo.com and I want to pass parameters in the java code.
Is this possible or not? If so how?
PS: I don't want to take input from user, rather the information will be in a variable, obtained from file.

Comment: You might want to check org.eclipse.help.ui.searchEngine extension point, it seems very close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It´s look like you want to offer a collection of different search engine based on a config file.

As "dgolovin" has pointed "org.eclipse.help.ui.searchEngine" has probably the functionality you are looking for.  Since Eclipse 3.1 it´s possible to define your own search engine in a variety of flavours (local search, Info Center, and Web search)

I see mainly two options:

1. Whereas you want to search in different sites you can define
   multiple web engines each one with it´s on site.

   %search.Eclipse.desc

more information about this on: 
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_help_ui_searchEngine.html

In the eclipse documentation you can read:

> Web search engine type has engine id org.eclipse.help.ui.web and
>   accepts one parameter url that represents a concrete search query with
>   the actual search string replaced with a substitution symbol
>   '{expression}', as in the following example:
>
> http://eclipse.org/search/search.cgi?q={expression}&ul=&ps=20&m=all
>   Web search results are shown as one link that will open the web
>   browser with the search string substituted in the url parameter.

1. Other option is to create your own engine type by implementing "org.eclipse.help.search.ISearchEngine" and contribute it on with the "org.eclipse.help.ui.searchEngine" extension point.

   Instances of XYZ Search search the XYZ site.

more information about this on: 
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_search_types.htm